# Unlink images in images folder on webserver that are not present in csv file field column

Tags: php, regex, image, csv, unlink

Basically I coded a autos site that automatically imports cars into a database from another, however the image references are displayed dynamically on the product page, based on image references and are based on registration plate IE* WG06HGY1.JPG,WG06HGY2.JPG etc (1-9 images)

So the always up to date daily csv import file called cars.csv which always contains the cars currently on sale, I then have created code to create a copy of that csv file named reg_plate_images.csv with only the registration field present.

How can I unlink/delete the thousands of unused car images on the server programmatically? I need to setup a script via cron do do this once a week.

I need to build an array and match the [regplate1-9.jpg] (preg match or str_pos) in the reg_plate_images.csv and if not equal to the images in the csv list, unlink the unused images in the folder.

Or another way might be:

Copy images that exist in csv etc to new folder images_temp
Delete/Unlink image dir
Rename images_temp to images.
Job Done.

Whats the best way of coding this?

Thanks.

Comment: without any useful details, at most we can link to you to http://php.net/glob http://php.net/foreach http://php.net/unlink

Comment: Thanks, this is what I mean, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: All I need to do is match the csv fields in one column of a CSV file (where cars exist for sale) and delete the rest which don't exist in the list, which are like this:

FULL REG
WG06HGY1.JPG,WG06HGY2.JPG,WG06HGY3.JPG,WG06HGY4.JPG etc
WXT55331.JPG,WXT553312.JPG,WXT553313.JPG,WXT553314.JPG etc
HELP543.JPG,HELP543.JPG,HELP543.JPG,HELP543.JPG etc

Comment: I'll have a go tomorrow at coding something, gah on this site, nice by the way but it seems you cannot hit enter to create a new line, and submits the comment instead, or have I drank too much!?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

First put all the images you want removed into regex as a `|` delimited list. Then use the regex to replace on the string.

Regex: `,?(?:WG06HGY2\.JPG|WG06HGY4\.JPG|HELP1\.JPG|HELP4\.JPG)(?=[\r\n,]|\Z)`

Replace with: nothing

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
FULL REG WG06HGY1.JPG,WG06HGY2.JPG,WG06HGY3.JPG,WG06HGY4.JPG
WXT55331.JPG,WXT553312.JPG,WXT553313.JPG,WXT553314.JPG,HELP1.JPG,HELP2.JPG,HELP3.JPG,HELP4.JPG
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
echo preg_replace('/,?(?:WG06HGY2\.JPG|WG06HGY4\.JPG|HELP1\.JPG|HELP4\.JPG)(?=[\r\n,]|\Z)/imsx','',$sourcestring);
?>
```

**After Replacement**

```
FULL REG WG06HGY1.JPG,WG06HGY3.JPG
WXT55331.JPG,WXT553312.JPG,WXT553313.JPG,WXT553314.JPG,HELP2.JPG,HELP3.JPG
```